# RRDTool Not Creating .RRD File

Tags: centos, cacti, rrdtool

I'm setting up Cacti and it seems the RRDTool isn't creating the .rrd file. This is on CentOS 6.9.

Here is what I've tried so far:

- Running the command as root to eliminate permissions.
- Running the same command on another machine that has just rrdtool installed.
- Creating a new directory /test with 777, and still same error.

I believe it's an issue with the command itself, however it was generated by Cacti so unsure how there could be a syntax issue.

**Do you see any issues with this below command?

Am I right in thinking it should just execute if just rrdtool is installed?**

Here is the original command from Cacti:

```
/usr/bin/rrdtool graph - \
--imgformat=PNG \
--start='-180000' \
--end='-30' \
--pango-markup  \
--title='Name - FloatingPointGraph' \
--slope-mode \
--base=1000 \
--height=150 \
--width=500 \
--alt-autoscale-max \
--lower-limit='0' \
--color BACK#F3F3F3 \
--color CANVAS#FDFDFD \
--color SHADEA#CBCBCB \
--color SHADEB#999999 \
--color FONT#000000 \
--color AXIS#2C4D43 \
--color ARROW#2C4D43 \
--color FRAME#2C4D43 \
--font TITLE:11:'Ariel' \
--font AXIS:8:'Ariel' \
--font LEGEND:8:'Courier' \
--font UNIT:8:'Ariel' \
--slope-mode \
--watermark 'Generated by Cacti®' \
DEF:a='/usr/share/cacti/rra/GraphName.rrd':'OtherName':AVERAGE \
LINE1:a:''
```

The error it reports is

```
ERROR: opening '/usr/share/cacti/rra/GraphName.rrd': No such file or directory
```

Comment: the rrdtool command mentions a 'rra' subdirectory, your error message doesn't... Does it exist? If not, rrdtool wouldn't be able to create the .rrd

Comment: Yes sorry a typo when I copied the error from me testing to another directory, have updated the question.

Comment: Aha! Great now I see the issue - the poller isn't running therefore the graph wasn't created with the create command. Though I did test manually running the poller before, but that must not of worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rrdtool graph` takes an existing .rrd and should create (using your command) a colorful png image.

If you'd like to create a .rrd file, that'd be `rrdtool create ...` maybe you're missing one more important setup step in cacti.

Comment: Yes this was the issue. The poller isn't properly running so the graph was not created. Manually running the poller has created the graph, so now I'll look into why that's not running. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!